# How to Make CSS3 Columns Display Properly

Tags: html, css

I am working on a website that uses CSS3 colums to break up the text of the article to three columns. In it's current state, there is a  few paragraphs, an unordered list and a few more paragraphs.

I want the article to essentally read like a newspaper, but CSS is breaking this up in a really perculiar way, and I cannot figure out how to fix it. The current website is the [Hospital Safety Store](http://hospitalsafetystore.com). Thanks for your help!

Comment: Include your code in the question.

Comment: provide a fiddle or code

Comment: @shahe There is a link to the site in the question, it is the best way of showing the problem that I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite frankly, with purely css and nothing else you can't split the contents of a single div across multiple columns like that.

Each column should be it's own DIV, which means you'll have to pre-split the article into three. You could do this manually but it'd probably less of a headache to write some php on the back-end to break up the article programmatically.

I'd typically have one container-div that is the full width, and then have child div's for the different columns.

Comment: I don't want to span a div over multiple columns, I want it to essentially read like a newspaper. The CSS3 Columns property should let me do what i'm looking for (in theory) but it isn't.

Comment: ah ok my bad you can do what you want see:
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp
however it'll be a lot harder to style I guarantee that!

Comment: Looking at your code again, you have the columns styling set on the p tag, it should be on the div tag

Comment: You fixed it -- Amazing, thank you! @serakfalcon